# MvvmCross and Tombstoning

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone, mvvmcross

I am working through a basic MvvmCross (v3.0.3) example and I'm a little stuck on working out how to get state loaded back in when an application is tombstoned. At the moment I have a Portable Class Library with a single view model and one property. I also have a Windows Phone 8 application that references this PCL, binds to the view model and then binds a textblock to the property.

All works well because the value of the property is displayed on screen. I have setup the WP8 project to tombstone on deactivation and when I click the start button the ViewModel.SaveState method (don't have the code open, so this may not be the correct name) is called and I can populate the provided "bundle" with the value in the property.

But, when I return back to the application by pressing the "back" button there is no call to the corresponding ViewModel.ReloadState method. I was expecting a call to this method so I can load the data that was specified in SaveState.

Is there something I'm missing? Does the "tombstone on deactivation" option not cause this to happen in MvvmCross?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tombstoning code in v3 is brand new - and it's not been fully worked through on all platforms yet - although I have personally tested it in on WinRT and Android.

On WindowsPhone I've also left one feature open - mainly because I didn't quite know what to put in it...

The feature that you need to implement is loading and saving of state within your pages - see the two empty virtual methods in `MvxPhonePage`: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Views/MvxPhonePage.cs#L54

The code for serializing/deserializing text to/from an `MvxBundle` is pretty easy - just use `IMvxSavedStateConverter` - see the Droid code in: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs#L59

It may be that there is some common code that I could use on all Windows Phone apps...

Comment: Hi Stuart. I notice that the LoadStateBundle method on MvxPhonePage doesn't provide access to the same IMvxBundle from SaveStateBundle. Would I be correct in thinking that I would manage the saving/loading of data myself and not rely on the IMvxBundle? Also, is the plan to use ViewModel.SaveState and ViewModel.ReloadState on Windows Phone?

Comment: Bit busy in Texas today... but basically the Pages that need to do tombstoning need to implement LoadStateBundle and SaveStateBundle - they need to work out where (in isolated storage?) they will save and load the bundle data (a string-string dictionary). After you've implemented that then the tombstoning *should* just work.

Comment: Sorry again for not being available to answer this more fully yesterday - just busy. If it didn't work... let me know!